# AngularJS How to remove query string before hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.3, with html5Mode disabled (see below).

When Facebook's OAuth redirects back to my site, the route's hash is added after the `?code` query string:

> `https://example.com/?code=<token>#/route`

How can I remove the query string? When I use `$location.search()` it ignores everything before the `#` so I can't seem to manipulate the `?code` param.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: false,
    requireBase: false
}).hashPrefix('');
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable html5 mode? I think facebook is correctly adding the anchor on the end of your callback URL.

Comment: Just a hint: AngularJS is = angular1 where Angular is angular2. Damn synonyms but thats how the versions are named.

Comment: What else have you tried to manipulate the `?code` param? What exactly do you want to do with it?